# what can I say on the series of the complex coefficient of $f(x)=2x^3 +x^5 + 5$

Tags: fourier-series

Lets assume than $c_n$ is the complex coefficients of the fourier series of $f(x)=2x^3 +x^5 + 5$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$

is it true to argue $$\sum {c_n}=5$$ and the series is absolutely converge?

The only thing I recognize here is that the function is odd. how should I use this? what is the right approach here? should I really calculate $c_n$?

Comment: You did not define $f(x)$.

Comment: As the function's odd your series will result in a sines one...but I can't see why you think that infinite series equals $\;5\;$ .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy fixed

Comment: $5=f(0)=\sum c_n$ follows by standard theorems in Fourier series. But absolute convergence is complicated and you will have to actually compute $c_n$'s for this.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think there is a theorem that states that if f is continuous differentiable on the interval so it's fourier series is uniformly converge, does it make sense?

Comment: @Sagigever Yes, the Fourier series converges uniformly. But absolute converence is a different matter.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but if the Fourier series is uniformly converges I can infer from weiresstress M test that $\Sigma |c_n|$ is absolute converge, am I wrong in my assumption?

Comment: If $f_n(x)=\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n}$ for all $x$ then the series $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent but not absolutely convergent.